# Python rq.worker not honoring Django's LOGGING config

Tags: python, django, python-rq

I am trying to run a standalone script outside of a Django app that interfaces with a Redis queue and uses the Python `rq` module. Everything is working fine but somewhere in either upgrading to Python 3.8 (from 2.7) or upgrading from Django 2.2 (from 1.11) or from `rq` to 1.2.2 (from 0.13) `rq` stopped honoring the Django `LOGGING` config. Here is what my Django `settings.py` file looks like:

```py
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        },
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "null": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.NullHandler"
        },
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "simple"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django.request": {
          "handlers": ["console"],
          "level": "ERROR",
          "propagate": True
        },
        "api": {
          "handlers": ["console"],
          "level": "DEBUG",
          "propagate": True
        },
        "worker": {
          "handlers": ["console"],
          "level": "DEBUG",
          "propagate": True
        },
        "rq.worker": {
          "handlers": ["console"],
          "level": "ERROR",
          "propagate": True
         }
    }
}
```

And here is what my `worker.py` looks like:

```py
import django
django.setup()

import os
import logging
import redis
import multiprocessing
from rq import Queue, Connection
from rq.worker import HerokuWorker

logger = logging.getLogger("worker")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    redis_url = os.getenv("REDISTOGO_URL", None)
    if redis_url:
        conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)
        listen = ["high", "default", "low"]
        thread_count = int(os.getenv("WORKER_THREAD_COUNT", "4"))
        logger.debug("Setting up worker script, threads=%d", thread_count)

        with Connection(conn):
            workers = []
            for i in range(thread_count):
                worker = HerokuWorker(map(Queue, listen))
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker.work)
                workers.append(p)
                p.start()
    else:
        logger.error("Could not find REDISTOGO_URL environment variable")
```

You can see I have `rq.worker` set to an `ERROR` level, but I'm getting `INFO` messages out on the console. This used to work just fine, but unfortunately I didn't notice this until after I finished upgrading everything. I tried removing the `rq.worker` section out of `settings.py` and the messages still get printed, but not in the format I defined. So I know my `settings.py` file is getting read properly. Has anyone else come across this or have any suggestions? I really do not want to have to fork `rq` just to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, 5 minutes after posting this I decided to look at the `python-rq` source and I found that the `work` method takes in a `logging_level`. This is what the new work line looks like:

```py
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker.work, kwargs={"logging_level": "ERROR"})
```

Everything seems to be working as expected now.

Comment: A more generic answer is: `some_worker.work(logging_level=logging.WARNING)`

rq seems to ignore logging.config.dictConfig loglevels too, so it's the only way to fix this.